# How to properly convert element sizes from HTML to PDF using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to convert HTML TO PDF using JSPDF, After conversion, the Font Sizes / Image Sizes are not according to the HTML.

I am exploring JSpdf document also: [https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-html.html#~html](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml)

Can you guys recommend any documentation which can help me set sizes of elements relative to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

set unit to points

```
const doc = new jsPDF({
   unit: "pt",
});
```